# Regex: How to match all strings that start with one underscore and print them without the underscore?

Tags: python, regex

My regex so far is `(?<=_)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b`

The input text is:

```
Calculate the _area of the _perfectRectangle object.

The _id and _age variables are both integers.

__invalidVariable _evenMoreInvalidVariable_ _validVariable
```

The output should be:

```
area,perfectRectangle

id,age

validVariable
```

But instead is:

```
area,perfectRectangle

id,age

invalidVariable,validVariable
```

How to match strings that start with only 1 underscore?[image]

Comment: `__invalidVariable` shouldn't match because it has two leading underscores? You only want to match single leading underscores?

Comment: Yes @IainShelvington, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: [(demo)](https://regex101.com/r/EA0w6o/1)

```
\b_{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b
```

> _{1} : one `_`
>
> ([...]) : get what in this `[...]`

Code for cheking:

```
import re
data= '''
Calculate the _area of the _perfectRectangle object.

The _id and _age variables are both integers.

__invalidVariable _evenMoreInvalidVariable_ _validVariable
'''

re.findall(r'\b_{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b', data)
# ['area', 'perfectRectangle', 'id', 'age', 'validVariable']
```

Comment: Cool approach. I wonder how and why is this working when the string (_test) is at the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: @prsnr thanks;) , edited answer, you can use `\b` instead of `\s`

Comment: It's working both ways but I wonder why it's working with \s?
\s means that it must match one space, right? But there is no space at the beginning of a sentence (at least not a visible one).
https://i.ibb.co/8Y3WH9t/image.png

Comment: @prsnr yes exactly with `?`  in `\s?` you set whitespace is optional

Answer (score 1):

You can assert an `_` to the left that by itself is not preceded by a char:

```
(?<=_(?<!\S_))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXLwb0/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MvqW7r)

```
import re
 
regex = r"(?<=_(?<!\S_))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b"
 
s = ("Calculate the _area of the _perfectRectangle object.\n\n"
    "The _id and _age variables are both integers.\n\n"
    "__invalidVariable _evenMoreInvalidVariable_ _validVariable\n\n"
    "_validVariable_test"
    )
 
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['area', 'perfectRectangle', 'id', 'age', 'validVariable']
```

Or with a capture group:

```
(?<!\S)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BpOKSv/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ewfp3P)

Comment: Thank you for that, but I accidentally found that it's not working in every scenario. Example: _validVariable_test matches only _test and it must not match anything. Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/LNZ16f9/image.png

Comment: @prsnr Then you can use `(?<!\S)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b` https://regex101.com/r/BpOKSv/1